# Repeatedly run a shell command until it fails?

Tags: bash

I've written a [fuzzy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing) test that fails unreliably. I've added some debug code, but now I want to run the test until it fails so I can gather the debug output.

I've setup the test so I can run it using:

```
./runtest
```

My current solution is to write an `untilfail` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
$@
while [ $? -eq 0 ]; do
    $@
done
```

Then use it:

```
untilfail ./runtest
```

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Side note: habitually quote "$@".

Answer (score 479, accepted):

`while` takes a command to execute, so you can use the simpler

```
while ./runtest; do :; done
```

This will stop the loop when `./runtest` returns a *nonzero* exit code (which is usually indicative of failure).

To further simplify your current solution though, you should just change your untilfail script to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while "$@"; do :; done
```

And then you can call it with whatever command you're already using:

```
untilfail ./runTest --and val1,val2 -o option1 "argument two"
```

Comment: It's good to also point out that `[` is a command. It's a common misconception with new users that `[` is part of `if` and `while` syntax.

Comment: How could I get a count of how many times it ran before it failed?

Comment: @GrantJ: it's actually really simple. Put `count=0` before the loop, then instead of `:` in the loop (a no-op), put `(( count++ ))` - this increments the counter.

Comment: A productivity hack: If you're on a system with `say` and a speaker you can use `while ./runtest; do :; done && say test failed` to be notified if it ever stops

Comment: @Schneems: worth noting that `say` is macOS-specific.

Comment: will it work, my command is like this (set -x; cat scripts/script_006.rb | heroku run console --no-tty | tee /tmp/set_a_$(date +%s) | tee /tmp/output)

Comment: @american-ninja-warrior: if your command is that complicated, consider just sticking it in a script file and calling that script.

Comment: Worth noting for non-shell-savvy folks like me that the space after `do` in the above _is_ significant. You'll get a syntax error without it.

Comment: ```retry() { while "$@"; do :; done; }```

Answer (score 20):

If you don't want to wrap a complex pipe line into a shell script or function then this works:

```
while true; do 
  curl -s "https:..." | grep "HasErrors.:true"
  if [[ "$?" -ne 0 ]]; then 
    break
  fi
  sleep 120
done
```

The HTTP request in this case always returns 200 but also returns some JSON which has an attribute "HasErrors":true when there is an error.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, and saved me trying it 20 times to get the bash syntax exactly right. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

One can also use the [`watch`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/watch.1.html) command with the `-e` flag which runs the command until an error occurs (and then freezes the output until a key is pressed):

```
watch -e ./runtest
```

The only downside of using watch is that there's a mandatory delay of at least 0.1s between runs:

```
watch -e ./runtest -n0.1
```

With `watch` you can also highlight output changes between runs (`-d`) or exit when the output of the command changes (`-g`).

Comment: Note that the argument passed in `watch -e ./runtest -n0.1` should be positioned *before* the command given to watch.

Comment: In other words `watch -e -n0.1 ./runtest`

Answer (score 5):

Having had a similar problem in a system that had shell retry logic duplicated everywhere I made a dedicated tool to solve this called "retry":

```
retry --until=fail ./runtest
```

A more complex example:

```
retry --until=fail --message="test succeeded" --delay=1 ./runtest
```

Tool available from https://github.com/minfrin/retry.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install run-one
run-one-until-failure COMMAND [ARGS]
```

For more information:
https://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2013/09/introducing-run-one-constantly-run-one.html