# How can I run a tagged cucumber test multiple times?

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber

## Scenario

I currently have a number of tests in cucumber which are all under one specific tag so that those specific ones can be run again and once I am happy with my changes they would then be changed to a more generic one where they run as part of a CI suite etc.

The command that I use to currently run that group of tests is:

```
cucumber features --t @web1
```

What can I add onto this command to make these specific tests run in a loop? i.e. I'd like to run these specific tests under this tag, 20 times say (instead of having to wait for the to complete and enter the command in manually each time).

I've tried to have a look around for some examples but didn't find anything specific for my case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest wrapping the `cucumber` command in a simple bash loop, such as:

```
for i in {1..20}; do cucumber features --t @web1; done
```

This will run the whole suite 20 times; it's (almost) equivalent to just running the command manually 20 times.

You could also consider doing something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12967264/1954610) - i.e. re-run the same test indefinitely, until they fail. Assuming the purpose of this is to help track down intermittent failures.

Comment: p.s. Hi Jas! :)

Comment: thanks! Could I also utilise some more advanced functionality like a Cucumber Rake?

Comment: Yes, this is also possible. In order to run cucumber via rake, you need to `require 'cucumber'` and `require 'cucumber/rake/task'` in the project `Rakefile`. See more here: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cucumber/Cucumber/Rake/Task

Comment: You *could* even perform the loop within rake, too - i.e. define a rake task that takes the name of another rake task as a parameter, and call `invoke` on it. But that's most likely overkill, if you could achieve that via a bash script like above! :)